# HelloAR example scene displaying default empty scene

Tags: android, arcore

I've followed the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android) to install the HelloAR example scene onto my Samsung Galaxy S8+ (Model number: SM-G955F) using Unity 2018.1.

However when I start the app I see this:

[image]

I didn't receive a notification to give the app permission to use the camera initially, but I allowed it manually and restarted the app, to no effect.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Seems like ARcore is not enabled. Have you installed ARcore on the device? Have you enabled ARcore in Unity? Go to Player **Settings > XR Settings** and tick the **ARCore Supported** box after you import ARCore.

Comment: Yeah I have the latest version of ARCore on my phone, and the setting is enabled in Unity.

Comment: what version of ARcore are you using in Unity?

Comment: I was using v1.2.0 as provided by the page I linked earlier. It seems that downloading the official repo of the latest version has fixed my problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a problem with the version of the SDK I was using. I managed to fix the issue by downloading the latest files from the [official repo](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk), and replacing the existing files in my Unity project.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by unticking the Scenes/SampleScene which is ticked in build settings.

[image]

Comment: Also, click Add Open Scenes to see the _actual_ scene that has to be included in the build.